# iOS: CFTypeRef disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, keychain

I'd like get username/password out of my keychain. for this I followed this guide:

[Simple iPhone Keychain Access](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html)

But this part is not allowed with ARC:

```
NSData *result = nil;    
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(
                  (CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,                                            
                  (CFTypeRef *)&result);
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ARC only manages Objective-C types. If you cast to Core Foundation types you have to tell ARC who owns the variable by using `__bridge`, `__bridge_retained` or `__bridge_transfer`.

Here's [Apple's official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) on toll-free bridging under ARC, or see [this blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) (scroll down to Toll-Free Bridging) for a great overview.

For example:

```
NSData *inData = nil;
CFTypeRef inTypeRef = (__bridge CFTypeRef)inData;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(
                   (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, 
                   &inTypeRef);
```

Comment: thank you simon. I already used `__bridge` but for `(CFTypeRef *)&result);` it didn't work.. Xcode noticed: Incompatible types casting 'NSData *__strong *' to 'CFTypeRef *' (aka 'const void **') with a __bridge cast

Comment: Separate out your cast from your dereference. Something like this: `CFTypeRef r = (__bridge CFTypeRef)result; OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &r);`

Comment: didn't work. leelang solution for some reason did. xcode 7.3

Answer (score 1):

```
CFTypeRef inData = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(
                   (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, 
                   & inData);
NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)inData;
```

Comment: "Try this" is not very useful since it doesn't explain what was wrong of how to fix it in another case.